# Plotly Express: Order of elements in plot (python)

Tags: plotly-python, plotly-express

When using Plotly Express, the easiest way to add multiple traces seems to be the "Add Trace Convenience Methods", such as `fig.add_scatter`. My problems is that when using this method, it seems to me like there is no way to to force this added trace to the top of the drawing.

The following example code produces a graph where the red "trace 1" markers are hidden behind the blue markers created using Plotly Express. How could one go about putting this layer on top of the draw order? I have tried messing around with the `stackgroup` parameter, but this had no effect.

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.scatter(x=np.random.rand(20000), y=np.random.rand(20000))

fig.add_scatter(x=np.random.rand(5), y=np.random.rand(5),
                mode='markers', marker=dict(size=40))

fig.show()
```

[image: Example Plotly graph]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in Plotly Express, because that doesn't support multiple axes, but:

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

# Create figure with secondary y-axis
fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=np.random.rand(20000), y=np.random.rand(20000)),
    secondary_y=False
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=np.random.rand(5), y=np.random.rand(5),
               mode='markers', marker=dict(size=40)),
    secondary_y=True
)

fig.show()
```

[image: plotly-express-order-of-elements-in-plot-python]

You might then need to align both axes as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63720344/1913230).